# How would i implement what's hot in parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am going through [this](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-saving) tutorial

It shows how to create an object in the backend. It say's that the object is created with some id but how would i know this object id is retrieving it ? I mean i cannot see the object id in the web!

I want to implement a news app , which basically stores url's in they are visiting in the backend , and i would like to load in the what's hot area, all the most visited url's

I know how to store the url ,but i need a good way to implement this sort of algorithm

Comment: How did it go? Need any more help?

Comment: yes the approach you told was good enough !but what about i have asked specific question in parse ?i can only give you a upvote

Comment: It's not really clear what your specific question is. If you have existing code, point to where in the code you would like to improve. Otherwise I'd have to write the entire program for you :)

Comment: yes coding it .. would surely post the code , but it will take time :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you have to break the problem down into parts.

1. query for the url - if you get a hit, then update the counter
2. if no hit, then store the url and a counter with value of 1

If you know the url is never changing, you can just query for the url the user uses. If it's changing for the same domain, then you can parse it somehow, to query for parts of the url.

You can also store the url locally on the phone and build an index: [url:objectId]. That way you could just update the counter with the objectId. This is a good way I think. If you go this route you will have to:

1. check against local objectId.
2. If no object id for this url, store > on callback from parse, save the url and object id
3. if objectId -> update counter with that id.

And yes, you can see the object id in the web.

[image]